# unrecognized selector sent to instance in collection view method numberOfItemsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

While I add the `UICollectionView` `Delegate` and `Datasource` with storyboard as same as `Objective C` then, I am getting the following error -

```
collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb74482b200'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add in class -

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
```

implement following method -

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yourCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


        return cell      //return your cell
    }
```